# How to make a setInterval function in such a way that it can stop and restart?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to make a function for my discord.js v12 bot that works in tandem with Disboard. Basically, it's a reminder function that pings a certain role every two hours to remind them to bump the server. I've been trying to work out a way so on !d bump, the bot stops the setInterval function through clearInterval, and starts the setInterval function again. However, I've been receiving an error that says that a certain object is not defined in the script.

Here's my code:

```
    client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === (`${prefix}setReminder`)) {
        message.channel.send("Interval has been set! Members will be reminded to bump the server every two hours!")
        var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "bumping ping")
        let intervalOne = setInterval(() => {
            message.channel.send(`${role} chop-chop! It's time to bump! `)
        }, 7200000);
        
        
    
    }
       
});
    client.on('message', async message => {
        if (message.content === "!d bump") {
            message.channel.send("Thank you for bumping the server. Please check back two hours later to bump the server again.")
            clearInterval(intervalOne)
             .then(setInterval(intervalOne)) | message.channel.send("I have successfully restarted the timer. You will get notified in two hours' time!")
        }



    });
```

Comment: what is the point of async signature defining your callback?

Comment: So do I just get rid of it? I just realized it. Thank you for raising that issue.

Comment: `intervalOne` is not defined in the bottom handler function because it is declared in the top handler function. Maybe you just need to `let intervalOne;` outside both handler functions and change `let intervalOne = ...` to `intervalOne = ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
module.exports = (client, message) => {
  if(message.content === '!d bump') {
    const pingRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'bumping ping');
    message.channel.send('Thank you for bumping the server. Please check back two hours later to bump the server again.')
    setTimeout(() => message.channel.send(`${pingRole} chop-chop! It's time to bump! `), 7200000);
  }
};
```

Is that good enough for you?